# Problems with php echo umlauts

Tags: php, mysql

I want to echo some informations out of my datatable. Now i have the problem, that every column, where i´m using umlauts (like ä,ö) doesn´t appear. The whole content of this column doesn´t appear not just the umlauts.

In mysql im using the latin1_swedish_ci.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use UTF-8 (just run this query before select something from the DB)

```
<?php
...
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
...
?>
```